# Emgu.CV tracker init issue

Tags: c#, .net, emgucv

I am new to the c# image processing scene getting and getting
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'byte[*,*,*]' error from:

```
qrCode.KCFTracker.Init(new Image<Bgr, byte>(newFrame), roi);
```

this new frame is initialized in:

```
Bitmap newFrame = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
```

Comment: Check that there actually is a constructor for Image that takes a bitmap as input. Otherwise you will need to copy the pixel data from the bitmap to the emgu image yourself.

Comment: Turns out there was a separate library named Emgu.CV.Bitmap and there was a conversation method that turns a bitmap into a mat()